# Why cant I watch Netflix on this OS (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: netflix

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit) and can't watch Netflix, just wondering if there’s a way round this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu supports watching [Netflix](http://www.netflix.com/) in [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html) browser version 37+.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, sadly.  At least with Chrome version 43.

Comment: Note that support for Chrome on 32-bit OS's as well as Precise will halt in March of 2016. Those affected by this decision may need to seek alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You need google Chrome 37+. take a look for the announcement here https://insights.ubuntu.com/2014/10/10/watch-netflix-in-ubuntu-today/

#### You can also use Pipelight with wine to do it

Install Pipelight in Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pipelight-multi
```

Enable Sliverlight to play Netflix

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
```

Install Netflix desktop app in Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
```

[image]

All rights are reserved for the owner [itsfoss](http://itsfoss.com/netflix-ubuntu-1404-desktop-app/)

Comment: Netflix desktop is obsolete. I guess Netflix does not use Silverlight any more.

Comment: I really don't know, information according to the link, but do you have official link for your pretends?

Comment: It is obvious. If you can watch Netflix in Chrome, then silverlight is not needed any more. You prove it with your link.)) Before the only way was to use silverlight.

Comment: Sure using chrome is much better but I mean is it still available to use silverlight or no?

Comment: I do not know. Netflix is not available here. But silverlight is getting close to EOL. Microsoft is closing it.

Comment: It looks like Netflix is switching or has switched to HTML5. And it looks like silverlight has been already dropped by netflix.

Comment: I think they have have enable support for HTML5 - does not mean they are deprecating silverlight, because otherwise all the Internet Explorer victims will have problems....

Comment: @Wilf  IE can use HTML5, can't it?

Comment: Yeah not very well (better but not brilliant in recent versions) - trying to write (more complex) HTML5 for it is a absolute pain...

Comment: +1 On Chaletos, based on xubuntu 14.04, the Netflix-desktop app works great!  Chrome 48 doesn't work as-is.